# Apache Tomcat Server Shuts Down on Log Out

Tags: tomcat, windows-server

I start Apache Tomcat Server 9 by running startup.bat. But, the Server shuts down automatically as soon as I Log Out/Lock the Windows Server. I want the Tomcat Server to be up and running as long as the Windows Server is on, as I'm hosting a web portal. Please help me with a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Apache Tomcat as a Windows service in order to have it running headlessly in the background. All your foreground applications naturally get terminated as soon as you log out while windows services keep running in the background.

Looke here how to [setup Apache Tomcat as a service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services).

Comment: I've installed the service and ran it using the link you provided. Yet, I'm unable to access the web portal.